# How to use COUNTUNIQUE function within ArrayFormula and get a range result?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, count-unique

[image]

I have tried to use a `COUNTUNIQUE` function within `ArrayFormula` in cell 'A2' to get a result in the range like a column B that I've set a function cell by cell. But it returns only a single value. This is my formula in cell 'A2':

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(D2:D7,E2:E7,F2:F7,G2:G7,H2:H7))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(D2:K<>"", "♦"&ROW(A2:A)&"♥"&D2:K, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♥"))),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 COUNTUNIQUE(D2:H2);
 COUNTUNIQUE(D3:H3); 
 COUNTUNIQUE(D4:H4);
 COUNTUNIQUE(D5:H5);
 COUNTUNIQUE(D6:H6);
 COUNTUNIQUE(D7:H7)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. However, is there any way to set this form of formula in dynamic to last row of sheet? Thanks.

Comment: sorry for late reply. this answer works. but it's too difficult for me to understand it because i don't realize some syntax in this set of formula. However, Thank you for your help.

Comment: it basically assigns a row number to whatever values in range D2:K then it collapses all rows and all columns into one cell and splits it all in two columns. then it picks up unique values and count them up.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has interested me for a while. Basically, the solution from @player0 seems obvious to me. But it is difficult to read.

Perhaps using combined arrays and implicit endings search is more appropriate:

```
=INDEX(
  COUNTIF(
    UNIQUE(FLATTEN(
      {"" & ROW(C2:Z), ROW(C2:Z) & "-" & C2:Z}
    )),
    ROW(C2:Z7) & "-*"
  ) - 1
)
```

[image]