# How to combine COUNTUNIQUE and ARRAYFORMULA in a dynamic range of two or three ... or n rows

Tags: google-sheets, range, array-formulas, google-query-language, count-unique

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580964/how-to-use-countunique-function-within-arrayformula-and-get-a-range-result) but instead of counting unique occurrences row by row I would like to do it in a range formed by 2 rows or 3 three rows... or n rows (i.e. several rows and several columns).

Here's a [Google Spreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HTr0ehjP52MhWxjuZKhbvBlvv7_ul7GQrwWyHn3DkAQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(SORTN(FLATTEN(IFNA(
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(A3:E<>"", 1)*ROW(B3:B))-(ROW(B3)-1), 1, ROW(B3))&"♂"&VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(A3:E<>"", 1)*ROW(B3:B))-(ROW(B3)-1), COLUMNS(A:E)*G3, COLUMNS(A:E)*G3)/COLUMNS(A:E))-
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(A3:E<>"", 1)*ROW(A3:A))-(ROW(A3)-1), 1, 0)*(G3-1)&"♀"&
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(A3:E<>"", 1)*ROW(A3:A))-(ROW(A3)-1), COLUMNS(A:E)*G3)-(ROUNDDOWN(
 SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(A:E)*G3, 0)/COLUMNS(A:E))*COLUMNS(A:E))-(COLUMNS(A:E)*G3*
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(A3:E<>"", 1)*ROW(A3:A))-(ROW(A3)-1), 1, 0)), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A3:E="",,ROW(B3:B)&"♀"&COLUMN(A:E)-(COLUMN(A3)-1)&"×"&A3:E)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0), 2, 0))), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), "♂"), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

---

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(SORTN(FLATTEN(IFNA(
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(B3:U<>"", 1)*ROW(B3:B))-(ROW(B3)-1), 1, ROW(B3))&"♂"&VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(B3:U<>"", 1)*ROW(B3:B))-(ROW(B3)-1), COLUMNS(B:U)*W3, COLUMNS(B:U)*W3)/COLUMNS(B:U))-
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(B3:U<>"", 1)*ROW(B3:B))-(ROW(B3)-1), 1, 0)*(W3-1)&"♀"&
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(B3:U<>"", 1)*ROW(B3:B))-(ROW(B3)-1), COLUMNS(B:U)*W3)-(ROUNDDOWN(
 SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(B:U)*W3, 0)/COLUMNS(B:U))*COLUMNS(B:U))-(COLUMNS(B:U)*W3*
 SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(B3:U<>"", 1)*ROW(B3:B))-(ROW(B3)-1), 1, 0)), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:U="",,ROW(B3:B)&"♀"&COLUMN(B:U)-(COLUMN(B3)-1)&"×"&B3:U)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0), 2, 0))), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), "♂"), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

---

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(SORTN(FLATTEN(IFNA(
SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Z3)<>"", 1)*ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Y3)))-(ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3))-1), 1, ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3)))&"♂"&VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(
SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Z3)<>"", 1)*ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Y3)))-(ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3))-1), COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3))*W3, COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3))*W3)/COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3)))-
SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Z3)<>"", 1)*ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Y3)))-(ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3))-1), 1, 0)*(W3-1)&"♀"&
SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Z3)<>"", 1)*ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Y3)))-(ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3))-1), COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3))*W3)-(ROUNDDOWN(
SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3))*W3, 0)/COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3)))*COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3)))-(COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3))*W3*
SEQUENCE(MAX(IF(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Z3)<>"", 1)*ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Y3)))-(ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3))-1), 1, 0)), 
QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Z3)="",,ROW(INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Y3))&"♀"&COLUMN(INDIRECT(Y3&":"&Z3))-(COLUMN(INDIRECT(Y3&X3))-1)&"×"&INDIRECT(Y3&X3&":"&Z3))), "×"), 
"where Col2 is not null", 0), 2, 0))), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), "♂"), 
"select count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

---

---

---

### [full explanation of the formula & how it works](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wQxW0p-U-Z92HCZRzZtfKYM3bi_plJ0Rcr8W3fPQYhY/edit#gid=1041024216)

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer player0. Please have a look at the new Sheet I have created ("With more data"), if the number of rows and columns in the spreadsheet grows the formula does not do what I actually want. I am sorry if I didn't explain myself properly in the first time.

Comment: @zagalico yes, the formula was written for small sets (up to 9 columns). answer and your sheet updated with an upgraded formula

Comment: Thank you very much again for your help. Since my data is subject to change I am looking for a formula that replicates COUNTUNIQUE where you can modify the size of the range to consider for uniqueness (either the number of rows or columns, or even the first row to start counting) giving you the uniques in that range. I have added some information to the sheet "With more data" for clarity.

Comment: Do you mean it is possible with your last formula? Thank you

Comment: I apologize in advance if I am mistaken or doing something wrong but when the number of Rows (W3) or the First Row (X3) are different from 3 it doesn't get the expected Uniques per range.

Comment: When you play around with the First Column (Y3) and the Last Column (Z3), e.g. Y3=B and Z3=E, it also doesn't get the expected Uniques per range. Please let me know if I am not tweaking your formula properly. Thank You!

Comment: Thank you again @player0. There is some adjustment needed to contemplate when W3 and X3 are different from each other.

Comment: Could you please fix the formula so it can handle different numbers in W3 and X3, or explain how your formula works? Thank You!

Comment: @zagalico answer updated. added full explanation of the formula

Comment: Great explanation! To contemplate when W3 and X3 are different from each other there was necessary changing
This:
-(ROW(B3)-1), COLUMNS(B:U)* **W3** , COLUMNS(B:U)*W3)/COLUMNS(B:U))-
for this:
-(ROW(B3)-1), COLUMNS(B:U)* **X3** , COLUMNS(B:U)*W3)/COLUMNS(B:U))-

Answer (score 1):

Since you already created a helper column in your spreadsheet, you can now use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H3));
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H4));
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H5));
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H6));
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H7));
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H8));
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H9));
COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(H10))
})
```

**Sample output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but actually what I am looking for is a formula that automatically handles all the data allowing you to work with hundreds (or as many as you want) of rows.